# xlwings can't find XL application

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I'm encountering a similar problem to these two questions:

- [xlwings gives “Invalid class string” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371276/xlwings-gives-invalid-class-string-error)
- [Error com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None) while writing dataframe into excel binary notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060655/error-com-error-2147221005-invalid-class-string-none-none-while-writing)

I recently uninstalled Office / Excel 2010 and I'm getting the error since then. I now only have Office 365, version 16.0.12872.20200 32bit. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing xlwings and the entire conda virtual env I'm working in. xlwings used to sometimes open Excel 2010 in spite of the newer install.

If I try to run `app = xw.App()`, `book = xw.Book()`, `book = xw.Book(r"path\to\file.xlsx")`, etc I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-437cd03edaeb>", line 1, in <module>
    app = xw.App()

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\emp_hist_env\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.impl = xlplatform.App(spec=spec, add_book=add_book)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\emp_hist_env\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._xl = COMRetryObjectWrapper(DispatchEx('Excel.Application'))

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\emp_hist_env\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 113, in DispatchEx
    dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0]

com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

If, however, Excel is running, then `app = xw.App()` still doesn't work, but `book = xw.Book()`, `book = xw.Book(r"path\to\file.xlsx")` do. It looks like xlwings can't find the excel app instance.

I'm trying to avoid reinstalling Office 365 or worse, Office 2010. Any ideas of easy settings I can change with xlwings or a quick registry tweak that may be fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by uninstalling both MS Office and Anaconda. I reinstalled Office 365 but ended up installing Miniconda instead of Anaconda to manage my environments a little more closely.

I noticed that in the install folder (`C:\users\user`) there was a `\.xlwings` folder I wish I'd noticed  right away. Deleting it after removing xlwings might have saved me some time. I only noticed it when I was clearing Anaconda files left by the uninstaller.